# Using R to sum values for cross-sectional unit in panel data

Tags: r, data-manipulation

All,

The company where I work gave me this data to work with. In short, it's TSCS data with the firm as the cross-sectional unit with time units as fiscal years. Each firm has various accounts. I'm interested in creating a total of money spent on each account for a given firm.

I can provide a simple illustration of the data below. Let `firm` be the cross-sectional unit of interest. Each `firm` has various accounts on which the company spends money. Some accounts are common to all firms, others are unique. Not every `firm` had money spent on an account in a given year. In fact, some were not eligible for accounts until later on in the data, and others drop out (as such, the panel data can be considered unbalanced). As such, the NAs in the data I was provided could be treated as 0s, though it's a little bit problematic. Some firms are eligible in a given year but don't receive money in an account. Other firms are ineligible because of drop-out or late entry.

The data look like this, and it was given to me in wide format. It's a simplified version for illustration. In this illustration, `firm=B` wasn't eligible for an account in FY1990 and `firm=C` drops out in FY1992.

```
firm   account   FY1990 FY1991 FY1992
A     Account 1    500    900   1000
A     Account 2     30     40     40
A     Account 3     NA     60     20
A     Account 4     NA     35     NA
B     Account 1     NA    340     60
B     Account 2     NA    500    800
B     Account 3     NA    800     NA
B     Account 4     NA     60   1000
C     Account 1   1000    400     NA
C     Account 5    500     60     NA
C     Account 8     60   1000     NA
D     Account 1    400    400    400
D     Account 2     NA   1000   1000
D     Account 3    300     40    300
D     Account 6     NA    300    300
D     Account 7    900    900   1000
D     Account 8   1000   1200   1500
```

What I'd like to do (and was told to do) was amend this data so that it looks like this:

```
firm   account   FY1990 FY1991 FY1992
A     Account 1    500    900   1000
A     Account 2     30     40     40
A     Account 3     NA     60     20
A     Account 4     NA     35     NA
A      TOTAL       530   1035   1060
B     Account 1     NA    340     60
B     Account 2     NA    500    800
B     Account 3     NA    800     NA
B     Account 4     NA     60   1000
B      TOTAL        NA   1700   1860
C     Account 1   1000    400     NA
C     Account 5    500     60     NA
C     Account 8     60   1000     NA
C      TOTAL      1560   1460     NA
D     Account 1    400    400    400
D     Account 2     NA   1000   1000
D     Account 3    300     40    300
D     Account 6     NA    300    300
D     Account 7    900    900   1000
D     Account 8   1000   1200   1500
D      TOTAL      2600   3840   4500
```

I could just as easily do this in Excel or some other spreadsheet program, but that would be tedious and it invites more human error than if I were to use R to program this. I'm not against creating a new data frame with the totals rather than trying to add a row underneath all the accounts for a given firm. It might be easier to just put a 0 for the total for a given firm ineligible for an account in a given fiscal year. I can always recode some zeroes as NAs next and automate that process as well.

My assumption is this would require a loop, but I'm a novice in R programming. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Reproducible code for this illustration is below.

```
firm <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D","D")
account <- c("Account 1","Account 2","Account 3","Account 4","Account 1","Account 2","Account 3","Account 4","Account 1","Account 5","Account 8","Account 1","Account 2","Account 3","Account 6","Account 7","Account 8")
FY1990 <- c(500,30,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1000,500,60,400,NA,300,NA,900,1000)
FY1991 <- c(900,40,60,35,340,500,800,60,400,60,1000,400,1000,40,300,900,1200)
FY1992 <- c(1000,40,20,NA,60,800,NA,1000,NA,NA,NA,400,1000,300,300,1000,1500)

Data=data.frame(firm=firm, account=account, FY1990=FY1990, FY1991=FY1991, FY1992=FY1992)
summary(Data)
Data
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Data)

dt[, rbind(.SD,
           c("TOTAL",
             lapply(.SD[, grepl("^FY[0-9]+", names(.SD)), with = F],
                    function(x){sum(x, na.rm = !all(is.na(x)))}
                   )),
           use.names = F),
     by = firm]
```

This works as follows: we iterate over firms (`by = firm`), and for each firm we stack (`rbind`)...

- the subset of data associated with that firm (`.SD`) on top of
- a vector starting with `"TOTAL"`, with the rest created by that long `lapply` call.

The `lapply` operates only with the data associated with one firm at a time. This data is stored in a special temporary data.table, `.SD`, mentioned above. Column names can also be named directly (but are not in this example).

The `lapply` call works as follows: we iterate over a list of vectors (selected by choosing columns with names that pass our `grepl` regular expression test), and for each vector we apply a special variant of the `sum` function.

This variant on the sum function looks at the full vector `x` where, again -- this vector is chosen from the list we are iterating over and only has rows associated with one firm at a time -- and checks if there are any non-`NA` entries in `x` (that is, if `!all(is.na(x))`). If there are, those entries are summed treating any `NA`s as zero (since `na.rm=TRUE`); if not, it returns `NA` (since `na.rm=FALSE` and we have `NA`s).

For details on the `na.rm` argument, look at `?sum`. Similarly, details on the functions above (`grepl`,`lapply`,...) can be found by searching with `?term` or `?"term"`.

The `by=firm` option then stacks the firms' results and adds "firm" as the first column.

This is the result:

```
    firm   account FY1990 FY1991 FY1992
 1:    A Account 1    500    900   1000
 2:    A Account 2     30     40     40
 3:    A Account 3     NA     60     20
 4:    A Account 4     NA     35     NA
 5:    A     TOTAL    530   1035   1060
 6:    B Account 1     NA    340     60
 7:    B Account 2     NA    500    800
 8:    B Account 3     NA    800     NA
 9:    B Account 4     NA     60   1000
10:    B     TOTAL     NA   1700   1860
11:    C Account 1   1000    400     NA
12:    C Account 5    500     60     NA
13:    C Account 8     60   1000     NA
14:    C     TOTAL   1560   1460     NA
15:    D Account 1    400    400    400
16:    D Account 2     NA   1000   1000
17:    D Account 3    300     40    300
18:    D Account 6     NA    300    300
19:    D Account 7    900    900   1000
20:    D Account 8   1000   1200   1500
21:    D     TOTAL   2600   3840   4500
    firm   account FY1990 FY1991 FY1992
```

You will have to install and load the `data.table` package first.

Comment: I'd add "TOTAL"'s as you calculate them - right now accounts that are named e.g. "VerySpecialAccount10" would be sorted incorrectly

Comment: another issue is your replacing `0`'s with `NA`'s - what if you actually have a total equal to `0`

Comment: @eddi Good point. I don't know how to add "TOTAL" rows as they are calculated. Alternately, one could prefix TOTAL with a character that comes very late in sorting, I guess. What do you think could be done to address the issue of erroneous NAs?

Comment: Ah, dickoa has a nice solution for the NA problem.

Comment: Very cool stuff, @eddi ! I'm going to make a further change to save on parentheses. It seems to still run correctly for me, but feel free to roll it back.

Comment: ha! I didn't know that `x` is a default variable name for `FUN` - do you know where/if that's documented?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30275/discussion-between-frank-and-eddi)

Comment: This answer would be *much* more useful if there were *any* explanation about how it works. Please can you add one or two sentences describing the process?

Comment: @SimonO101 Yeah, it has become a little baroque. I've added some explanation and made it a community wiki. (I'm not sure if that's suitable here, but figured that the answer has already had a lot of input and editing from others.) Feel free to fix it up further.

Comment: +1 Thanks Frank. This is great and a really useful resource. I wouldn't be able to fix it up further, because you already know a lot more about data.table than me (which is why i asked for some clarification - I am learning all the time). Cheers!

Comment: This, and dickoa's offer, were both very useful. I was able to apply it to my real data very quickly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just another option if you want to do it the `data.frame` way.

```
require(plyr)

sumNA <- function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))

res <- rbind(Data,
             ddply(within(Data, account <- "TOTAL"), .(firm, account), 
                           numcolwise(sumNA))
             )


(res <- res[order(res$firm), ])

##    firm   account FY1990 FY1991 FY1992
## 1     A Account 1    500    900   1000
## 2     A Account 2     30     40     40
## 3     A Account 3     NA     60     20
## 4     A Account 4     NA     35     NA
## 18    A     TOTAL    530   1035   1060
## 5     B Account 1     NA    340     60
## 6     B Account 2     NA    500    800
## 7     B Account 3     NA    800     NA
## 8     B Account 4     NA     60   1000
## 19    B     TOTAL     NA   1700   1860
## 9     C Account 1   1000    400     NA
## 10    C Account 5    500     60     NA
## 11    C Account 8     60   1000     NA
## 20    C     TOTAL   1560   1460     NA
## 12    D Account 1    400    400    400
## 13    D Account 2     NA   1000   1000
## 14    D Account 3    300     40    300
## 15    D Account 6     NA    300    300
## 16    D Account 7    900    900   1000
## 17    D Account 8   1000   1200   1500
## 21    D     TOTAL   2600   3840   4500
```